# Increasing the size of character varying type in postgres without data loss

Tags: postgresql

I need to increase the size of a character varying(60) field in a postgres database table without data loss.

I have this command

```
alter table client_details alter column name set character varying(200);
```

will this command increase the the field size from 60 to 200 without data loss?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Referring to [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-altertable.html) documentation, there would be no data loss, `alter column` only casts old data to new data so a cast between character data should be fine. But I don't think your syntax is correct, see the documentation I mentioned earlier. I think you should be using this syntax :

> ALTER [ COLUMN ] column TYPE type [
>   USING expression ]

And as a note, wouldn't it be easier to just create a table, populate it and test :)

Answer (score 94):

The correct query to change the data type limit of the particular column:

```
ALTER TABLE client_details ALTER COLUMN name TYPE character varying(200);
```

Comment: I had to run ALTER TABLE public."client_details" ALTER COLUMN "name" TYPE character varying(200);

Answer (score 6):

Yes. But it will rewrite this table and lock it exclusively for duration of rewriting — any query trying to access this table will wait until rewrite finishes.

Consider changing type to text and using check constraint for limiting size — changing constraint would not rewrite or lock a table.

Comment: Just a note for the future.  In 9.1 some types of data type changes won't require a rewrite. I believe this case for making a varchar larger like this.

Comment: @JustBob do you have a reference to documentation on this?

Comment: From [PostgreSQL 9.1 Release Notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release-9-1.html): E.10.3.4.2 Allow `ALTER TABLE ... SET DATA TYPE` to avoid table rewrites in appropriate cases. But @JustBob is wrong – increasing length of varchar type does require a rewrite, but changing a varchar to text (and adding constraint for length checking) does not.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this below sql command
`ALTER TABLE  client_details 
ALTER COLUMN name TYPE varchar(200)`

Answer (score 3):

Changing the Column Size in Postgresql 9.1 version

During the Column chainging the varchar size to higher values, table re write is required during this lock will be held on table and user table not able access 
till table re-write is done.

Table Name :- userdata
Column Name:- acc_no

ALTER TABLE  userdata ALTER COLUMN acc_no TYPE varchar(250);

Answer (score 2):

From [PostgreSQL 9.2 Relase Notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html) E.15.3.4.2

> Increasing the length limit for a varchar or varbit column, or removing the limit altogether, no longer requires a table rewrite.