# Change the character varying length with ALTER statement?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, types, ddl

I am trying to change length of a column from `character varying(40)` to `character varying(100)`.

Following the method described in this question [Increasing the size of character varying type in postgres without data loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488428/increasing-the-size-of-character-varying-type-in-postgres-without-data-loss)

```
ALTER TABLE info_table ALTER COLUMN docs TYPE character varying(100);
```

Tried with this command but returning syntax error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TYPE" at character 52

Is there any change needed in this command? Using PostgreSQL version 7.4.30 (upgrade to 9.2 in process :) ).

I tried this same command in test db which is now upgraded with version 9.2. It is working fine there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the column type on the fly was not possible in the ancient version 7.4. [Check the old manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/sql-altertable.html) You had to add another column, update it with the (possibly transformed) values and then drop the old one, rename the new one - preferably in a single transaction. With side effects on views or other depending objects ...

To avoid this kind of problem altogether I suggest to use plain `text` or `varchar` (without length modifier) for character data. [Details in this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word `TYPE`, that syntax wasn't recognized 10 years ago, but you should be fine without it.

Comment: Got this 
ALTER TABLE info_table ALTER COLUMN docs character varying(100);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "character" at character 52